# bluring background when mousewheel scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blur

I was referring to the following link to blur background on mouse scroll.

http://codepen.io/sotayamashita/pen/pqLcv

The code is shown as below:

HTML:

```
<div id="blurred-image-container">
    <div class="img-src" style="background-image:url('https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/fit/c/1600/1280/gradv/29/81/60/darken/25/0*I7mXgSon9oco-rim.jpeg')"></div>
    <div class="img-src blurred-img" style="background-image:url('https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/fit/c/1600/1280/gradv/29/81/40/darken/50/blur/50/0*I7mXgSon9oco-rim.jpeg')"></div>
</div>

<div class="article">
  <h1>Medium</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-src {
    position: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.blurred-img { opacity: 0; }

.article {
  width:500px;
  height: 2000px;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -103px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // Get scroll position
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
    // scroll value and opacity
    opacityVal = (s / 150.0);
    // opacity value 0% to 100%
    $('.blurred-img').css('opacity', opacityVal);
});
```

Then, the background picture that needs to be blurred is not at the very top of the page.  My webpage is quite long and the background needs to be blurred is at the very bottom of the page.

I think the following code is trying to set the point where bluring starts to occur at the top of the page.  I think there are more than 2000px to scroll down before reaching to the section I want to blur the background.

```
    var s = $(window).scrollTop(), opacityVal = (s / 150.0);
```

Lets say my html document looks like this:

```
<div id="firstdiv">
    <p>long text goes here....</p>
</div>
<div id="seconddiv">
    <p>long text goes here....</p>
</div>
<div id="thirddiv">
    <p>long text goes here....</p>
</div>
<div id="blurred-image-container">
    <div class="img-src" style="background-image:url('https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/fit/c/1600/1280/gradv/29/81/60/darken/25/0*I7mXgSon9oco-rim.jpeg')"></div>
    <div class="img-src blurred-img" style="background-image:url('https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/fit/c/1600/1280/gradv/29/81/40/darken/50/blur/50/0*I7mXgSon9oco-rim.jpeg')"></div>
</div>

<div class="article">
  <h1>Medium</h1>
</div>
```

I want the background page to blur when the page is scroll down to #blurred-image-container section.

How can I modify the jQuery to work that?

Comment: this is quite confusing, show only minimal code which you have tried and elaborate more about what you are expecting

Comment: @Vilas Kumakar Hi, I am expecting to get blur effect shown in this website https://medium.com/good-music/f160ba9e6c52 If you scroll way down, there are two backgrounds blurs as you scroll down. The blurring effect doesn't start until your mouse is scrolling down the section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="out">

</div>
<div class="in">

</div>

out {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background: url('background') no-repeat;
}
.in {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:olive;
}  

 $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var pixs = $(document).scrollTop()
    pixs = pixs / 100;

    var scroll;
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(scroll);
 *if(scroll>606)
    {
    $(".out").css({"-webkit-filter": "blur("+pixs+"px)","filter": "blur("+pixs+"px)" })    
    }*

});


});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I tried that solution. Bluring works well.  Though, there is one issue.  It seems bluring starts to happen when I scroll down from the very top of the page.  Can blurring happen when my mousewheel scrolls pass the <div class="out">?

Comment: wow that is very nice.  Can I ask you one more question?  What if one of div I have above .out has 100vh height? it think the height would change depending on the browser of the viewer.  Can the scroll>606 be replaced by height calculated from top of the document to .top?  thank you so much

Comment: Just replace 606 with any height u want it will work

Answer (score 1):

This solution will require a separate element for the background but uses SVG filter to allow emulating motion blur in vertical direction.

It calculates the difference between last and current scroll position and uses that for a blur value. It debounces as well via using `requestAnimationFrame()`. It's easy to adopt to support a separate value for horizontal blurring as well.

You may want to tweak scale and max values for the blur, below some initial values only.

```js
var blur = document.getElementById("fltBlur");
var prevY = 0;
var reqId;

window.onscroll = function() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(reqId);
  reqId = requestAnimationFrame(motionBlur)
};

function motionBlur() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  var n = Math.min(32, Math.abs(y - prevY));
  blur.setAttribute("stdDeviation" ,"0 " + n);
  prevY = y;
}
```

```css
html, body {width:100%; height:300%}
#cont {
 width:100%;
 height:300%;
 background:url(//i.imgur.com/47zcWet.jpg);
 -webkit-filter: url(#svgBlur);
 filter: url("#svgBlur");
 }
```

```html
<svg style="position: absolute; top: -99999px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="svgBlur" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
    <feGaussianBlur id="fltBlur" in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
<div id=cont></div>
```